# how to sort date and null date in android?

Tags: android, json, sorting, arraylist

i get json data and i want to i get date and nulldate store in arrylist .how to sort date and null date data set in listview sort date in below. i store in all data in All_Approval_data_dto class.
my code given below: please check it and what i missing it?

```
static final Comparator<All_Approval_data_dto> byDate = new Comparator<All_Approval_data_dto>() {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");

        public int compare(All_Approval_data_dto ord1,
                All_Approval_data_dto ord2) {

            java.util.Date d1 = null;
            java.util.Date d2 = null;
            try {
                d1 = sdf.parse(ord1.lastModifiedDate);
                d2 = sdf.parse(ord2.lastModifiedDate);
                if (d1 == null) {
                    return (d2 == null) ? 0 : -1;
                }
                if (d2 == null) {
                    return 1;
                }

            } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block`
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return (d1.getTime() > d2.getTime() ? -1 : 1); // descending
            // return (d1.getTime() > d2.getTime() ? 1 : -1); //ascending
        }

    };
```

My error in below:

```
11-02 11:03:58.861: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(473): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-02 11:03:58.861: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(473): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-02 11:03:58.861: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(473):     at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.parse(SimpleDateFormat.java:1201)
11-02 11:03:58.861: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(473):     at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:642)
11-02 11:03:58.861: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(473):     at com.serana.Approval$2.compare(Approval.java:155)
11-02 11:03:58.861: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(473):     at com.serana.Approval$2.compare(Approval.java:1)
11-02 11:03:58.861: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(473):     at java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:320)
11-02 11:03:58.861: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(473):     at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:185)
11-02 11:03:58.861: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(473):     at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:169)
11-02 11:03:58.861: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(473):     at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1907)
11-02 11:03:58.861: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(473):     at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:1972)
11-02 11:03:58.861: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(473):     at com.serana.Approval$4.onItemSelected(Approval.java:79)
11-02 11:03:58.861: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(473):     at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:864)
11-02 11:03:58.861: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(473):     at android.widget.AdapterView.access$200(AdapterView.java:42)
11-02 11:03:58.861: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(473):     at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:830)
11-02 11:03:58.861: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(473):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-02 11:03:58.861: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(473):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-02 11:03:58.861: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(473):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-02 11:03:58.861: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(473):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-02 11:03:58.861: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(473):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-02 11:03:58.861: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(473):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-02 11:03:58.861: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(473):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-02 11:03:58.861: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(473):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-02 11:03:58.861: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(473):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please replace your try/catch block with this code

```
try {

            if (d1 == null) {
                return (d2 == null) ? 0 : -1;
            }
            if (d2 == null) {
                return 1;
            }

            d1 = sdf.parse(ord1.lastModifiedDate);
            d2 = sdf.parse(ord2.lastModifiedDate);

        } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block`
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

**-** Better use `Joda` library to compare the date.

**-** First you need to parse them. Use `DateTimeFormat`:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
DateTime dateTime1 = fmt.parseDateTime(string1);
```

**-** Then use DateTime.isBefore(..) method to compare them:

`if (dateTime1.isBefore(dateTime2))`

Comment: but vivek i coudn't  DateTimeFormatter Add in method.

Comment: @crickpatel0024.. where are you encountering the problem, can u pls point me out....

Comment: @crickpatel0024 are you able to format the date and time, pls see to that first

Comment: @crickpatel0024 just a piece of advice, when ever you are about to integrate a piece of code into your project, test it out before hand by making a demo of it.

Comment: kumar first i create DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"); and i get error  at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.parse(SimpleDateFormat.java:1201)
11-02 11:03:58.861: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(473):     at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:642)